# How can I use Metacity and its themes with Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, metacity

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming
Now Trusty don't support Metacity themes.

So... Is there a another way to enable Metacity in Unity? For example, gnome-session-flashback can return a desktop with Gnome-Metacity. Any similar tool but for Unity?

Answer (score 0):

No, as you can see, all the calls, functions, etc. in Unity were dropped and uses GTK instead. If you need any metacity theme, I would recommend just finding a GTK equivalent or changing the window manager from Compiz to Metacity.